# How can i update values in a Excel by using Java

Tags: java, excel

```
int nxtcol=0;
for(int k=0;k<values.length;k++)
{
    Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(k);
    row1.createCell(nxtcol).setCellValue(values[k]);

}
wb.write(fileOut);
nxtcol++;
```

Here only the first columns is written. How can I write all column in excel file?

Comment: which API you are using for handling excel file?

Comment: nxtcol is always zero so only first column cells are written.